# Codeigniter Sub Modules

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI. I want to create Sub Modules under Modules.

I have folowed this link and created Moudules.
https://github.com/jenssegers/CodeIgniter-HMVC-Modules

But i have few minor issue in that.

here is the example how i want the url.

```
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/login
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/notification
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/Manage Users
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/Reports

www.yourdoamin.com/users/login
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/calendar
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/Manage Customers
www.yourdoamin.com/superadmin/Reports

www.yourdoamin.com/login
www.yourdoamin.com/booking
```

So basically i want three main modules and there will be lot of sub modules in each.

I have added a module folder under the main module but it does not work.

like this

```
   -module
        -superadmin
            -modules
                 -login
                 -reports
```

this is not working

Thanks to all

Comment: what does your config.php look like where you setup the $config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'module/' => '../module/',
  );